# Detect if using IME for input in browser

Tags: browser, google-docs, ime

How would I go about checking whether the user is using an IME to input text? For instance, if you look at Google Docs, they seem to use some kind of intermediate IFrame to capture it before putting it in the actual document `<div>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C DOM Level 3 specifies the event `compositionstart` and friends for detecting IME input. For browsers that don't support those events, some hacking around is required.

The Closure library has an example for this: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_events_imehandler.js.source.html